# Why is the movie named 'Bird Box'?

Tags: title, bird-box

I do get that in the end that Malorie and her kids end up in an old school for the blind which happens to house lots of birds, but it's a school in the end.

But why is this movie named 'Bird Box'? Is there any significance to this name?

Comment: I can’t tell if you missed the fact that they carry a box holding three birds with them for the entire journey on the river, or if you know that and still don’t see why that was used as the name of the movie.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I didn't miss it.. although I didn't see why the movie had to be named bird-box as opposed to "Blindfolds" (more important subject in the movie than the birds in the bird-box).. I just didn't know how relevant the title and the movie were. Like why??  i have my answer now (the blind school is a "metaphor of the bird-box" which i didn't relate tbh).. I genuinely was hoping there was a deeper reason for the name than a straightforward "birds in box"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bird box, also known as a [nest box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nest_box), is a man-made enclosure to allow animals a place to nest.

> A nest box, also spelled nestbox, is a man-made enclosure provided for
>   animals to nest in. Nest boxes are most frequently utilized for birds,
>   in which case they are also called birdhouses or a birdbox/bird box,
>   but some mammalian species may also use them. Placing nestboxes or
>   roosting boxes may also be used to help maintain populations of
>   particular species in an area. The nest box was invented by the
>   British conservationist Charles Waterton in the early 19th century to
>   encourage more birdlife and wildfowl on the nature reserve he set up
>   on his estate.

Although I have yet to see the film (or read the book), I do know that it is a horror survivalist story about not being able to look at an entity and this then plays on themes about examining motherhood/maternal instincts and the nature of man vs the nature of animals with there being a literal bird box for human beings...

Answer (score 5):

They (all people shown at the end) are enclosed in that building just like birds in a bird box. So the building is the bird box for them.

Comment: Also the people in the middle third of the story are enclosed in a different building. Also, the birds are manipulated and affected by powers they can’t understand. Those powers want the birds to live but are also putting the birds in great danger. The birds have no choice - larger forces will determine their fate. The characters in the movie have a somewhat similar experience. They place themselves at the mercy of the river without much control over whether they survive. The mysterious evil and good (luck?) forces are beyond their understanding.